# GUI with Tkinter - PNG background image not displaying?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently trying to get a .png image to display in the background of a GUI I was creating to ask questions to a user. However, my background would not be displayed. I have looked at similar questions to this, which suggest to assign the image to the label.image so it won't be deleted in garbage collection. However, even when I have done this it will not show. The print statement of the image returns "pyimage1", so I know the program accepts it for what it is, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import tkinter
import os

#Defining main window to work in
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x500")
root.title("GUI testing program")

questionText = "Question placeholder"
responseText = "Response text placeholder"

#Defining the image to use (got the exact filepath by using os.getcwd() )
imgfile         = tkinter.PhotoImage( file = (os.getcwd() + '\\test_img.gif') )
#Debugging print, which returns 'pyimage1'
print(imgfile)
#Assigning the image to the background label which will hold the image
backgroundimg   = tkinter.Label(root, image = imgfile)
backgroundimg.image = imgfile
backgroundimg.place(x = 0, y = 0, relx = 1.0, rely = 1.0, anchor = 'nw')

#Other items on the screen at the time
questionLabel   = tkinter.Label(root, text = questionText, font = ('Verdana',30), bg = '#ffffff', fg = '#000000', relief = 'sunken', justify = 'left', anchor = 'w')
questionLabel.pack(fill = 'x', side = 'top')
inputText       = tkinter.Entry(root, text = "Type answer here", font = ('Verdana',30), bg = '#ffffff', fg = '#000000')
inputText.pack(fill = 'x', side = 'top')
submitButton    = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Submit", font = ('Verdana',20), bg = '#2c3e50', fg = '#000000', activebackground = '#b3b3b3')
submitButton.pack(side = 'right', anchor = 'n')
responseLabel   = tkinter.Label(root, text = responseText, font = ('Verdana',20), bg = '#0000ff', fg = '#ffffff')
responseLabel.pack(side = 'left', anchor = 'n')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting the upper-left corner of the image (`anchor='nw'`) at the bottom-right corner of the GUI (`relx=1.0, rely=1.0`). The entire image is off screen.

This is the documentation for `relx`; `rely` is identical except for the direction:

> Location specifies the x-coordinate within the master window of the
>   anchor point for window. In this case the location is specified in a
>   relative fashion as a floating-point number: 0.0 corresponds to the
>   left edge of the master and 1.0 corresponds to the right edge of the
>   master. Location need not be in the range 0.0-1.0. If both -x and
>   -relx are specified for a slave then their values are summed. For example, -relx 0.5 -x -2 positions the left edge of the slave 2 pixels
>   to the left of the center of its master.

Comment: Oh thanks, thought it did length relative to the size of the screen!

Comment: @D.Lee: object size can be specified with `relwidth` and `relheight`.